# How can you have more than 10 colors represented in the graph and legend in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, spline

I currently have 12 lines representing 12 different people in a spline graph. I noticed that once it goes beyond ten, the colors and shapes repeat. This makes it hard to distinguish between different people. In the future I will probably have more than 12, which will make this default behavior an even bigger problem.

Is there any way to extend the default number or perhaps to decide on the colors for a pre-set number of people beforehand? This last option would not be ideal if it couldn't be responsive to dynamic numbers of people.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8QufV/

Comment: Most likely belong to another site, like Programmers or something similar. "Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development."

Comment: This is **entirely** _on-topic_ but you've not included any code. Yes you can have more than 10 colours, but the comment in question doesn't provide more than 10 colours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can define colors in array: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors